# Generating variables from db content?

Tags: php

I am querying a database to get 6 values in my params table suing this;

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM params");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {

    $param = $row['value'] ;

 }
```

is this right, if so is their away i can add one to the variable name each time round so i get $param1, $param2....

I dont want to have to send a query to the database for each param, is it possible to get them all like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpliest way is to use an array:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM params");

$param = array();
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $param[$i] = $row['value'] ;

    $i++;
}
```

Than you get $param[0], $param[1], ...

Answer (score 0):

You can create variable names like this:

```
      ${'var'.1}
      ${'var'.'1.cat'}
      ${'var'.$x}
      ${$y.$x}
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a design flaw.  But what you can do is:

```
$count = 1;

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM params");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $paramname = 'param' . $count++;
    $$paramname = $row['value'] ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find the `list` function useful - http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php

```
list($param1,$param2,$param3,$param4,$param5,$param6) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

Probably more use when using descriptive variables, just a thought.